# Is hair transplantation allowed in islam

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, fiqh

Assalamu alaikum,
My question is as in the subject, is hair transplant allowed in islam? Can we go through the process of adding new hair from other area of the head where there is more growth of hair. **No artificial hair**

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to learn more about our site and the stack exchange model by taking our 2 min. [tour] and visiting our [help].

Answer (score -1):

Aleykomosalam
 yes, Islam allow it and it isn't illicit

Comment: @Milad gh  this is not a opinion driven forum or blog please support your claims with evidences from the Quran or sunnah